# How to use FlexiLayout to get data from plain text file to be able to automatically structure it?

Tags: abbyy

Does anybody knows if it is possible to use FlexiLayout Studio **not** for recognizing PDFS/Images, but for working with plain text files? My goal is the ability to create a document definition file to automatically structure all the data inside some plain text files, without the need for building multiple regular expressions to separate fields.

Also, the files I need to work with contains multiple times the same group of fields in which there is or could be tables.